# Find peaks and bottoms of graph and label them

Tags: python, pandas, plot

```
      df1
      Date           Topic  Return
      1/1/2010        A,B     -0.308648967
      1/2/2010        C,D     -0.465862046
      1/3/2010        E        0.374052392
      1/4/2010        F        0.520312204
      1/5/2010        G        0.503889198
      1/6/2010        H       -1.730646788
      1/7/2010        L,M,N    1.756295613
      1/8/2010        K        -0.598990239
      ......
      1/30/2010       z         2,124355
 Plot= df1.plot(x='Date', y='Return')
```

How can I find highest peaks and smallest troughs for this graph and label these special points with corresponding Topics?

Answer (score 4):

This depends a little bit on your definitions of "peak" and "trough". Oftentimes, a person might care about smoothed peaks and troughs to identify broad trends, especially in the presence of noise. In the event that you want every fine-grained dip or rise in the data though (and if your rows are sorted), you can cheat a little bit with vectorized routines from `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

d = np.diff(df['Return'])
i = np.argwhere((d[:-1]*d[1:])<=0).flatten()
special_points = df['Topic'][i+1]
```

The first line with `np.diff()` compares each return value to the next return value. In particular, it subtracts them. Depending a little on your definition of a local peak/trough, these will have the property that you only have a feature you're looking for if these pairwise differences alternate in sign. Consider the following peak.

```
[1, 5, 1]
```

If you compute the pairwise differences, you get a slightly shorter vector

```
[4, -4]
```

Note that these alternate in sign. Hence, if you multiply them you get `-16`, which **must** be negative. This is the exact insight that our code uses to identify the peaks and troughs. The dimension reduction offsets things a little bit, so we shift the indices we find by 1 (in the `df['Topic'][i+1]` block).

**Caveats**: Note that we have `<=` instead of strict inequality. This is in case we have a wider peak than normal. Consider `[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]`. Arguably, the string of 2's represents a peak and would need to be captured. If that isn't desirable, make the inequality strict.

Additionally, if you're interested in wider peaks like that, this algorithm still isn't correct. It's plenty fast, but in general it only computes a superset of the peaks/troughs. Consider the following

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
```

Arguably, the number 3 is the only peak in that dataset (depends a bit on your definitions of course), but our algorithm will also pick up the first and second instances of the number 2 due to their being on a shelf (being identical to a neighbor).

**Extras**: The `scipy.signal` module has a variety of peak-finding algorithms which may be better suited depending on any extra requirements you have on your peaks. Modifying this solution is unlikely to be as fast or clean as using an appropriate built-in signal processor. A call to `scipy.signal.find_peaks()` can basically replicate everything we've done here, and it has more options if you need them. Other algorithms like `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt()` might be more appropriate if you need any kind of smoothing or more complicated operations.

Comment: My return have both negative and positive numbers . Is there any difference for calculating "d" in your answer or not

Comment: Nope. The `d` only cares about differences. Vertical scaling won't affect it at all.

Comment: This is my data https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8qbigmljy20oz4/J.xlsx?dl=0 . I check your code with this data but I dont know why your code cant not find the right result

Comment: Works fine for me. Would you mind updating your question with the input data (not a dropbox link since those go dead eventually) and also what your desired output is? Troughs and peaks have multiple definitions, and knowing exactly what you want will be helpful.

Comment: I want to find Peaks : date of 5-6 highest returns and troughs :date of 5-6 lowest returns on the graph and label these points with the topic . And sorry , I will update it now

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Take an example data
data = {"Date":["date{i}".format(i=i) for i in range(10)], "Topic":["topic{i}".format(i=i) for i in range(10)], "Return":[1,2,3,2,1,2,4,7,1,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

dates = np.array(df["Date"].tolist())
returns = np.array(df["Return"].tolist())

# Calculate the minimas and the maximas
minimas = (np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(returns))) > 0).nonzero()[0] + 1 
maximas = (np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(returns))) < 0).nonzero()[0] + 1

# Plot the entire data first
plt.plot(dates, returns)
# Then mark the maximas and the minimas
for minima in minimas:
    plt.plot(df.iloc[minima]["Date"], df.iloc[minima]["Return"], marker="o", label=str(df.iloc[minima]["Topic"]))
for maxima in maximas:
    plt.plot(df.iloc[maxima]["Date"], df.iloc[maxima]["Return"], marker="o", label=str(df.iloc[maxima]["Topic"]))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Example dataframe:

```
   Date   Topic  Return
0  date0  topic0       1
1  date1  topic1       2
2  date2  topic2       3
3  date3  topic3       2
4  date4  topic4       1
5  date5  topic5       2
6  date6  topic6       4
7  date7  topic7       7
8  date8  topic8       1
9  date9  topic9       3
```

Plot it produces:
[image]

Comment: Then append all the topics together to get the label. Would that work for you. On a  separate note, I would recommend you use plotly for the plotting work.

Comment: I used your code but I cannot find the right results for maximals . My return have both negative and positive number . Are there any difference here?

Comment: No, this should work for both negative and positive nums, Can you give an example where it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: This is my data https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8qbigmljy20oz4/J.xlsx?dl=0  . I try to sort the log_ret1 column again and check the graph ,but the result is not  really good